# how to calculate the textbock height and width in on load if i create textblock from code?

Tags: c#, windows-8, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml, actualwidth

```
TextBlock tbl= new TextBlock();
tbl.text="Kishore";

double x=tbl.ActualHeight;
double y=tbl.ActualWidth;
```

If i execute the code from the loaded event in Metro - winRT will return 0 for both.

How can I get the `ActualWidth` in the `Loaded` or `SizeChanged` event?

Comment: WPF had methods like arrange/measure, you gave available space and got dimensions as a result. Isn't there something similar in Jupiter?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Call [Measure()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.uielement.measure.aspx) then [Arrange()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.uielement.arrange.aspx) and then `ActualWidth` and `ActualHeight` will be updated.

Comment: First, Measure is called, then Arrange.

Answer (score 1):

Can also do this via

```
UpdateLayout();
testBlock.ActualWidth
```

This could be useful when calculating multiple objects heights and widths.

Answer (score 0):

```
TextBlock tbl = new TextBlock();
tbl.Text = "Kishore";

tbl.Measure(new Size(0, 0));

double x = tbl.ActualHeight;
```

Comment: A little explanation might help.