# How to calculate text Height, depending on constant width, font and size in Windows Store App

Tags: windows-runtime, height, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml

I need to calculate a `TextBlock` height in code in order to build a grid properly. I've seen a few examples, but `Graphics.MeasureString` namespace is different. How to do it in Windows Store App?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10556019/how-to-calculate-the-textbock-height-and-width-in-on-load-if-i-create-textblock). Basically you need to create a `TextBlock` and invoke the layout procedures to force a layout pass to give you `ActualWidth/Height` of the `TextBlock`.