# Calculate Font baseline in WinRT

Tags: fonts, windows-runtime, baseline

I'd like to find out the [baseline of a font](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baseline_(typography)) in WinRT.

I've also calculated the size of text for a particular font by [creating a dummy TextBlock](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10556019/how-to-calculate-the-textbock-height-and-width-in-on-load-if-i-create-textblock), but I'm not sure how to calculate the baseline. Is this even possible in WinRT?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, what you are looking for is `FormattedText` [MSDN: [1](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.formattedtext.formattedtext.aspx) [2](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752098.aspx) ] that exists in WPF and doesn't exist in WinRT (i don't even think it's even in silverlight yet).

It will probably be included in a future version because it seems to be a very sought after feature, is sorely missed and the team is aware of it omission. See here: [http://social.msdn.microsoft.com](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winappswithcsharp/thread/380b4b7b-72e2-4435-b7f7-0d2afca4eac0/#db8a49dc-b252-4ffb-a128-02ed14ded2af).

If you are interested or are really, really in need of a way to measure the specifics of a type face you can try writing a wrapper for **DirectWrite** which to my knowledge is inside the WinRT available technology stack, however it is only accessible via C++

here is a couple of jumping off points for you, if you want to try:

- [these guys seem to actually be using DirectWrite in a WinRT app](https://bitbucket.org/nyamatongwe/metrosci/src/5c2b93bda000/Skeen/winrt/PlatWin.cxx)
- [this is a wrapper for C++ making DX available, DirectWrite would be
  much of the same](http://directxwinrt.codeplex.com/)

hope this helps, good luck -ck

***update***

I thought about this for a bit and remembered that `TextBlock`s have the oft forgotten property `BaselineOffset` which gives you the baseline drop from the top of the box for the selected type face!  So you can use the same hack everyone is using to replace `MeasureString` to replace a loss of `FormattedText`.  Here the sauce:

```
    private double GetBaselineOffset(double size, FontFamily family = null, FontWeight? weight = null, FontStyle? style = null, FontStretch? stretch = null)
    {
        var temp = new TextBlock();
        temp.FontSize = size;
        temp.FontFamily = family ?? temp.FontFamily;
        temp.FontStretch = stretch ?? temp.FontStretch;
        temp.FontStyle = style ?? temp.FontStyle;
        temp.FontWeight = weight ?? temp.FontWeight;

        var _size = new Size(10000, 10000);
        var location = new Point(0, 0);

        temp.Measure(_size);
        temp.Arrange(new Rect(location, _size));

        return temp.BaselineOffset;
    }
```

and i used that to do this:
[image: screenshot]

perfect! right? hope this helps -ck

Comment: Wow, yes that is perfect!
I had seen that property when searching for this problem, but for some reason had dismissed it... But it works exactly right.