# WinRT How to Get Pixel Width of given String

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, microsoft-metro, winrt-xaml, pixel

There is a solution here:

[FormattedText](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.formattedtext.aspx)

But Alas, this is not supported in WinRT. Is there a replacement/alternate for this in WinRT?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I manage to get around this with a HACK type of solution. My main requirement was to reserve space for some text. I used a fixed font and calculated space required for each "blank space". Once i knew this, the rest was trivial.

Comment: I have the same problem but have no clue of how to solve it by reading your answer.

Answer (score -1):

The following solution is taken from this answer:
[Calculate Font baseline in WinRT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15862600/calculate-font-baseline-in-winrt)

```
private double GetBaselineOffset(double size, FontFamily family = null, FontWeight? weight = null, FontStyle? style = null, FontStretch? stretch = null)
{
    var temp = new TextBlock();
    temp.FontSize = size;
    temp.FontFamily = family ?? temp.FontFamily;
    temp.FontStretch = stretch ?? temp.FontStretch;
    temp.FontStyle = style ?? temp.FontStyle;
    temp.FontWeight = weight ?? temp.FontWeight;

    var _size = new Size(10000, 10000);
    var location = new Point(0, 0);

    temp.Measure(_size);
    temp.Arrange(new Rect(location, _size));

    return temp.BaselineOffset;
}
```