# Find Height of Textblock / Text

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-store-apps

i try to calculate the height of [TextBlock](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.textblock.aspx).
I dont want to take the Textblock on some page. I just have to know the height of my Content.

I tried it this way, but it just returns 0

```
private static double CalculateContentHeight(string content, double width, double fontSize)
{
    //Nur einen Textblock ggf. um Ressourcen zu sparen
    TextBlock textblock = new TextBlock
    {
        FontSize = fontSize,
        Text = content,
        TextWrapping = TextWrapping.Wrap,
        MaxWidth = width,
        Height = Double.NaN

    };
    return textblock.ActualHeight;
}
```

If i take a existing TextBlock in XAML and just:

```
MyXAMLTextBlock.MaxWidth = 7;
double height = MyXAMLTextBlock.ActualHeight;
```

I get the right value for it.

I know there are possibilitys with Meassure() and Arrange() like in this [Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10556019/how-to-calculate-the-textbock-height-and-width-in-on-load-if-i-create-textblock), but Meassure(Size) takes the size paramter and i dont have the height for it.

I know that you can set the size on Auto with Double.Nan, but it doesnt compile with

```
double height = 9;
Size s = new Size(height, Double.Nan);
```

Maybe you can help me and thanks a lot.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have no idea why you are doing this. But with Measure and Arrange it is possible:

Just run this two lines before you return the ActualHeight:

```
textblock.Measure(new Size());
textblock.Arrange(new Rect());
```

Hope I could help you

Comment: Thank you! I will try this tomorrow. I need it to calculate a table withou creating it, because it takes to much memory.

Comment: Use Windows.Foundation and this sets the Actual Height/Width